# HTML Regex Selector

Tags: html, regex

I am trying to make a regex for HTML, I am coming up with a few minor issues regarding header html blocks to be selected and title in head for some reason,

To explain it better:

`<h5>Thing</h5>` will all be selected but I only want `<h5>` and `</h5>` selected and it's the same with `<title>Test</title>` I only want the html tags selected but it selects the whole thing,

here is my regex so far:

`/(<\/(\w+)>)|(<(\w+)).+?(?=>)>|(<(\w+))>/ig`

Comment: Don't parse HTML using RegEx, you will fail. Use something like the [HTML agility pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Rule 1: don't use RegEx to parse HTML. Rule 2: if you still want to parse HTML with RegEx, see rule 1.  [RegEx can only match regular languages, and HTML is not a regular language](http://stackoverflow.com/a/590789/930393)

Comment: I understand these replies, but this was just for a personal project and would like to try and finish this regex and as the only problem I am facing is explained above don't understand why no one else can solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here: `<(\w+).+?(?=>)>`

This says:

1. open an angle bracket
2. consume as many word characters as possible (min 1)
3. consume as few characters as possible (min 1)
4. make sure a closing angle bracket follows
5. consume the closing angle bracket

First of all, step 4 is superfluous; you know you will have a closing bracket next, otherwise step 5 will fail to match.

But the bigger problem is step 3. Let's see what happens on `<h5>Thing</h5>`:

1. `<`
2. `h5` (because `>` is not a word character any more)
3. `>Thing</h5`, because this is the least amount matched before a closing angle bracket (remember, matching 0 characters here is not an option)
4. Make sure next is `>`
5. `>`

Anyway, in the simple case, what you want can be done by `/<\/?.+?>/`. This will break if attributes have values that include a greater than symbol: `<div title="a>b">`. Avoiding this is possible, but it makes the regexp a bit more complex, kind of like this (but I may have forgotten something):

```
<\w+(?:\s+\w+(?:=(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'"][^\s>]*)?)?)*\s*>|<\/\w+>
```